# Uniformly minimum variance unbiased estimator of theta.

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Let $X_1,X_2,....X_n$ be a random sample from a population with probability density function 
$$f(x|\theta)=\dfrac{\theta}{2}e^{-\theta|x|} ,-\infty < x < \infty,\theta>0$$

Then a UMVE of $\theta$ is ?

Can someone tell me if i did everything right or not in the following steps. I dont have answer written for this problem in my solution manual.

**Steps :**

1.Its an even function that's why pdf changes as $$f(x|\theta)=\theta e^{-\theta x} ,0 < x < \infty,\theta>0$$
2.Using Rao blackwell theorem i found MVUE $\dfrac{n-1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i}$

Now MVUE is $\dfrac{n-1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i}$ or $\dfrac{n-1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} |X_i|}$ ? Please give your thoughts and tell me where did i follow wrong track?

Comment: How comes the first step?

Comment: $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)=2\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x)$$ if $f(x)$ is even. I am having bad feeling now i think i did something wrong .

Comment: Even though this integration equality holds, the density function cannot be rewritten.

Comment: Well doing that it instantly gave me  pdf of exponential distribution. Your arguments seems valid i never encountered this operation anywhere in my textbooks, it is the first time i applied integral property to any pdf. So any thoughts what could be an alternate for this problem?

Comment: @AlexFrancisco http://prntscr.com/i3x0z0 Options were given too . You can look at them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write 
$$f(x)=\dfrac{\theta}{2}e^{-\theta|x|}=h(x)g(\theta)\exp\left(\eta(\theta)\cdot T(x)\right)$$
with $h(x) = 1$, $g(\theta) = \theta/2$, $\eta(\theta)=-\theta$, and $T(x) = |x|$.

[It follows that $f$ is of the exponential family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family#Scalar_parameter).

Furthermore, note that the parameter space
$$\Theta=(0, \infty)\supset(0, 1)$$
so $\Theta$ contains an open set. Therefore, it follows that $T(\mathbf{X}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}|X_i|$ is sufficient and complete.

Next, we need to find the CDF of $|X_1|=|X|$. Observe that due to that $f$ is even,

$$F_{|X|}(x)=\mathbb{P}(|X| \leq x)=\mathbb{P}(-x\leq X \leq x)=\int_{-x}^{x}f(t \mid \theta)\text{ d}t=2\int_{0}^{x}f(t \mid \theta)\text{ d}t$$
and we can see that
$$\int_{0}^{x}\dfrac{\theta}{2}e^{-\theta|t|}\text{ d}t=\dfrac{\theta}{2}\int_{0}^{x}e^{-\theta t}\text{ d}t=\dfrac{\theta}{2}\cdot\dfrac{1}{-\theta}(e^{-\theta x}-1)=\dfrac{1-e^{-\theta x}}{2}$$
so it follows that $$F_{|X|}(x)=1-e^{-\theta x}$$
for $x > 0$, with probability density function
$$f_{|X|}(x) = \theta e^{-\theta x}$$
for $x > 0$ and $f_{|X|}(x) = 0$ otherwise, 
 hence $|X|$ follows an exponential distribution with mean $1/\theta$. [It follows that $T(\mathbf{X})$ has a Gamma distribution with $\alpha = n$ and $\beta = \theta$.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Characterization_using_shape_%CE%B1_and_rate_%CE%B2)

With some work, [it can be shown that $\dfrac{1}{T(\mathbf{X})}$ follows an Inverse-Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution#Related_distributions) with mean $\dfrac{\theta}{n-1}$ as long as $n > 1$; hence, $$\mathbb{E}\left[\dfrac{n-1}{T(\mathbf{X})}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\dfrac{n-1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}|X_i|}\right]=\theta$$
so by [Lehmann-Scheffe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmann%E2%80%93Scheff%C3%A9_theorem), $\dfrac{n-1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}|X_i|}$ is the UMVUE of $\theta$.

Comment: I followed same thing like you did. So we can apply integral property right? What about the argument alex made. Do i have to think before applying it?

Comment: @Damn1o1 You can't just "rewrite" the density without showing the work I did above or you could use a piecewise-transformation theorem.

Comment: And thank you for a thorough solution.

Comment: I did the work i just wrote the end result in the question.